# Grammar driven IDE?

Tags: ide

Use case: to explore a grammar in an interactive way, or as a more directed alternative to a standard IDE for programming.

What I want can be described as a IDE that

1. allows you to enter a grammar in its settings, for example as a list of production rules in some format. Here i am talking about production rules as in the sense usually defined in the context of formal grammars. One common format is backus naur form, but if you know of a program that allows more general formats (such as context dependent grammars) that would be welcome.
2. has an extreme form of intellisense: it does not only suggest code, but forces the programmer to select what production rules to use for different possible cursor positions, based on what production rules are allowed by the grammar defined in the settings (see 1.). That is, for example by using the arrow keys, a choice is possible between the possible production rules, for example in the form of a popup such as in intellisense. My understanding is that this is called a structured editor, structure editor, projection editor or syntax directed editor.
3. is runnable on Windows or Linux, or some OS which has an emulator that can run on Windows or Linux, or be open source.
4. has a manual that is in English or Swedish

Attempts to find such a program: I searched last year and remember I found something similar, the page was in Cyrillic (edit: my memory served me wrong, this is the site I was thinking about: http://programator.o-pro.cz/frey/) though so I didn't understand it at all. The other ones I found were about domain specific languages, their servers were screwed up though so the manual was not accessible. Besides that I only found remarks like "it was popular in the 80s, no one wants to do it now" which makes me hope maybe someone has the old programs from the 80s laying around.

I am not experienced in making text editors so I can't write my own program anytime soon

Comment: To clarify your question are you looking for natural language grammar or software programming language grammar?

Comment: I want the program to enforce/steer the input so that it complies with the grammar, by making the user choose what production rules to expand into. I am thinking the grammar could be given in form of a list of production rules with nonterminals and terminals.

Comment: I am learning direct2d now so maybe I'll be able to make my own soon...

Comment: The cyrillic thing you found was probably [JetBrains Nitra](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/Nitra/Home) - that's what I would have recommended. Unfortunately it's not in release state yet, more like beta stadium.

Comment: *Pure* grammar driven editors were a popular idea in the 80s.  They failed because people aren't driven by the grammar; they are opportunists.  This means the "structure editor" has to be able to not only suggest structure/grammar rules (yes, that part is still useful), but it has to be tolerant to arbitrary edits and programs that aren't syntactically legal most of the time.   There aren't many tools/IDEs that do this, that are available now.  There was a bunch of work on this at Berkely back in the 90s.

Comment: .... I doubt you will be able to do this with just pixel editing (direct2d); you need a *lot* of machinery to process grammars (that's actually a lot harder than it looks) and people also want "code completion in context" ,e.g, suggest something based on the identifiers already defined in the code.  That's *way* harder than just parsing.  I don't intend to rain on your parade; just be realistic about what you can build in a time frame you are willing to tolerate.

Comment: Code completion in context is only relevant for the terminals, I am thinking that the programmer moves through the different syntax tree nodes/suggestions with the keyboard so there isn't really necessary to do any parsing besides a lookup on the left hand sides of the production rules (at least at first)

Comment: I am thinking that the program is more like a way to explore the grammar than a text editor.

Comment: @Emil: That's exactly what the structure editors of 80s did.  Not a new idea.

Comment: @Ira: Well if you know of any place on the internet that has such editors please tell me. Old ideas can still be good and improved upon.

Comment: Really strange that it is so hard to find nowadays. Didn't anyone make backups haha :)?

Comment: @Emil:  I suggest you revise your question to follow the SR guidelines a bit more carefully.   If you do that, I'll raise an objection to the SR people who claim "this is unclear".   It wasn't to me.   Just because they don't know what it is does not mean they should close it for this reason.   ... I'll follow up with some pointers.

Comment: @Emil:  A rather famous system for this is "Harmonia".  See technical paper at http://harmonia.cs.berkeley.edu/papers/maratb-master.pdf.  A more recent approach is https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~NatProg/papers/Ko2006Barista.pdf.  One of the classic papers on this is Teitelbaum,T.and Reps,T., The Cornell ProgramSynthesizer: A Syntax-Directed Programming Environment, CACM 24,9,(1981),563-573.  You may find this Github project interesting: https://github.com/cheery/textended-edit/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Emil:  JetBrains claims to have a structure editor; they are pretty well respected:  http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/concepts/

Comment: @Emil:  This page contains a lot of interesting discussion about the topic:  https://pcmonk.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/why-dont-we-have-a-general-purpose-tree-editor/     I think the top 3 mentions there are  Xtext, MPS [list above under JetBrains] and MetaEdit+.    I have no specific experience with any of the tools listed in this or previous comments.  What might be closest to what you want is Xtext.

Comment: @Emil: Looks like my request worked.  You're welcome.

Comment: I have written a proof of concept program on my own now. Took me several minutes to unsuccesfully try to create a function using c++ grammar by just choosing production rules haha :-) If this is going to be useful it must allow direct user input.